# Execute custom command after performing pull using eGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Is it possible to configure such a custom setup within Eclipse?
I'd like to be able to ..

1. Open Eclipse
2. `pull` on my project

   - once `pull` completes, automatically run `myScript.sh` (which resides at root of the project)